# Why doesn't my DataTrigger update the SelectedIndex property of a TabControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, triggers, tabcontrol

I have a  `TabControl` which has its `SelectedIndex` property bound to a boolean value like this:

```
<TabControl>
    <TabControl.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TabControl">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsRunning, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="SelectedIndex" Value="1" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TabControl.Style>
    <TabItem Header="Foo" />
    <TabItem Header="Bar" /> 
</TabControl>
```

The `TabControl` should only switch to the second tab, if the `IsRunning`property changes to `True`, but the problem now is, that as soon as the `IsRunning` property changes, the TabControl does not update itself to display the second `TabItem`.

Is there a way to do this through XAML, or do I have to implement a `SelectedIndex` property in my viewmodel, that binds directly to the `SelectedIndex`of the `TabControl`?

Comment: Works here. Does your underlying ViewModel (the DataContext of the TabControl) raise a PropertyChanged event when IsRunning changes?

Comment: Interesting...yes, the PropertyChanged event is definitely raised.

Comment: If you set the SelectedIndex on the TabControl as a default [that would be a problem by the way](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx).

Comment: I suspect HB is right. If you set the `SelectedIndex` in the `<TabControl>` tag then the triggered value won't take effect because properties set in the `<TabControl>` tag will take precedence. If you want to set the `SelectedIndex`, do it in the `Style`

Comment: I didn't set the `SelectedIndex` property in the `TabControl` tag, I set it only in the style, exactly like in my example.

Comment: The interesting thing is, that my example code works, when I create a new project, but it doesn't integrate with my existing project.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me just as expected, if the property changes to true the tab switches. Maybe there's a [problem with the binding](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsldesigner/archive/2010/06/30/debugging-data-bindings-in-a-wpf-or-silverlight-application.aspx)? (Or did i misuderstand the question?)

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread but who knows someone else may stuble upon this just like me looking for an answer.

Solution: Just add a setter in TabControl style to set SelectedIndex to initial value. e.g. Setter Property="SelectedIndex" Value="0"

```
<TabControl>
    <TabControl.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TabControl">
            <Setter Property="SelectedIndex" Value="0" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsRunning, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="SelectedIndex" Value="1" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TabControl.Style>
    <TabItem Header="Foo" />
    <TabItem Header="Bar" /> 
</TabControl>
```